# How to display specific element from array in GET response

Tags: javascript, postman, web-api-testing

I am testing custom API through Postman. I send GET call, and, in response, I receive an array with many elements.
I am just wondering: is it possible to restrict response (in Pre-request script for example) to display only one element in Postman, based, for example, on ID comparison?
This is example response:

```json
"Data": {
        "P2PPayees": [
            {
                "Payee": {
                    "PayeeId": "1",
                    "FullName": "Wivhifgik",
                },
            },
            {
                "Payee": {
                    "PayeeId": "2",
                    "FullName": "Mupjidif",
                },
            },
        ]}
```

Comment: If the server allows you to restrict the response, then it's possible. You'll have to read the server's API documentation. If not, you'll have to filter the results yourself after they come back from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the server which sends the object. Read the documentation and have a look, if you can use query parameters to restrict the response. If the server doesn't support to restrict the response, you have to do it by your own programmatically.